# ttf converter solution for dynamic text geometries in three.js

Tags: three.js, typeface.js

I would like to generate dynamic text geometries given a ttf font file, and read from the Three.js [wiki](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Text-in-Three.js) that the only procedural way to do this is to embed a Typeface.js converted font file.

Unfortunately, I cannot find anywhere an online ttf->typeface converter. Indeed, the Typeface library site is down since a long time now, and I'm afraid it will never go online again.

The blender exporter solution exposed on the wiki doesn't seem to fit my needs either, first because I'm a blender total newbie, but mainly because it seems to be appropriate for static text only. I need a dynamic solution, and I need text geometry and not textures because I want to deform the text as I draw it along curves, with extrusions and bevels.

Is there any alternative way to do what I'm trying to do, or am I stuck with the basic font files provided with the threejs lib (and have only my eyes for cry) ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: As explained in section 4 of the wiki article you referenced, http://typeface.neocracy.org/fonts.html converts from tff to a JS format suitable for three.js

Comment: Thanks, I can read ;) But as surprising as it seems, the site appears magically to work again since you commented! Are you the typeface.js webmaster ?

Comment: The converter returns an internal server error :(

Comment: You shouldnt have messed with typeface.js administrator.